# How to add id into url with codeigniter like domain.com/$id

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm stuck with this: I want to change the name controller with my user id or passing a parameter in the index function and hide the controller , like domain.com/user_id without controller before user_id.
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have to set it in your routes have a play around with some thing like this

```
$route['add/link/(:num)'] = "admin/localisation/location/edit/$1";
```

or

```
$route['add/link/(:any)'] = "admin/localisation/location/edit/$1";
```

Also when you do dome thing like that in view or controller can do this to get id

`site_url('route or no route') . $this-uri->segment(what_ever_number);`

Comment: in this case im not using the number but i use  characters, i want to hide the controller like domain.com/fahmi

Comment: you would just have to set in the routes. the `/(:any)` lets you use numbers and or text good for subfolders.

Comment: But i have more than 1 class, if i have to use /(:any) and its will overwrite all, .  in this case i want my url like domain.com/ name_ user im stuck with this :((

Comment: Must be only default controller that can do that I think what your after. Otherwise you need routes I not think it possible what you are after.

Comment: I found solution every controller or class has to be defined in route.php it will be make like if conditional. thank you so much for the time hehehe :)